# overruling data frame index when plotting with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to plot with data frames, but sometimes, I want more control over my x-tick labels and it looks like the data frame index is 'overruling' my code.  here is the code:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'cycles':[0,'b',3,'d','e','f','g'],'me':[100,80,99,100,75,100,90], 'you':[100,80,99,100,75,100,90], 'us':[100,80,99,100,75,100,90]})
f, ax = plt.subplots()
x = test_df['me']
x.index = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']



print(x)
for a in ax.get_xticklabels():
    a.set_text('me')

print(ax.get_xticklabels()[0])
ax.plot(x)
test_df.plot(x = 'cycles', y = 'me')
```

any idea on easier ways to easily modify x-tick labels for data frames easily without changing the index of the data frame, but easily just on the fly making the x-ticks whatever I want for any data frame column I want?

Comment: I.e. I want to set individual x-ticks, but I had to change the index in order to have the tick labels that I wanted, if I didn't, the index of the data frame would be the x-tick labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `xticks` within `DataFrame.plot`. This is basically just a dummy to ensure the number of tick labels is correct.

Then just set the tick labels manually after the plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'cycles':[0,'b',3,'d','e','f','g'],
                   'me':[100,80,99,100,75,100,90]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
test_df.plot(x='cycles', y='me', ax=ax, xticks=test_df.index)
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(test_df['cycles'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

But you should be a bit hesitant of how the xticks aren't automatically generated. Line plots make sense when your values are ordinal. It doesn't seem obvious to me that `0` should be connected with `'b'` anymore than `'e'` should be connected to `'f'`. In this situation a bar plot makes sense, and not-surprisingly, the xticks are generated without issue.

```
test_df.plot(x='cycles', y='me', kind='bar', legend=False)
```

[image]